# Mailchimp inline CSS

Tags: css, inline, mailchimp

I'm trying to adjust padding and add rounded edges to the body container in MailChimp. I've got this far, but nothing happens and scratching my head trying to figure out if this can actually be achieved. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

`<td class="bodyContainer" style="padding-left: 16px;padding-right: 16px;border-radius: 24px;"></td>`

Thanks!

Comment: Can we get more information about your code??

Comment: The code (above) is added using a code block in MailChimp, which is meant to inject custom code into a campaign.